# 'serialized' field in schema still needs manual unserialization?

Tags: 6, database

I've modified my schema so that I can store an array of items in one field:

```
"required_product" => array(
  "type" => "text",
  "length" => 'medium',
  "not null" => TRUE,
  "default" => "",
  "serialize" => true,
),
```

This works great when using drupal_write_record, as the array data is correctly serialized before putting it into insert/update query and executing.

However, I still have to manually serialize when I extract the data - example:

```
$form_state["values"] = db_fetch_array(db_query("SELECT * FROM {amh_shop_discounts} WHERE discount_id=%d", $discount_id));
$form_state['values']['required_product'] = unserialize($form_state['values']['required_product']);
```

This is less useful - shouldn't it do both?

Currently running Drupal 6.22

Answer (score 5):

This is just a guess, so correct me if I'm wrong...

I think that automatic unserialization is not possible because the schema is not loaded by db_query. While [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7) loads the schema definition before writing to the database, db_query simply executes the query string you put into it, without knowing which schema definition the query relates to.

Comment: Well, that does make sense - and I could probably write up a function that does access the schema in the same way (probably should be in the fetch_object/fetch_array methods), but is there already something that does this?

Comment: No, there isn't. Accessing the schema is slow, especially in Drupal 6, you don't want to do this when doing SELECT queries. You know your data, you probably want a _load() function anyway and then you can do the unserialize there.